# Groovy AST @Canonical: constructors are not generated for ancestor's fields

Tags: groovy, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree

Two classes:

**Parent**

```
@Canonical
class Parent {
    int id
}
```

**Child**

```
@Canonical
class Child extends Parent {
    String name
}
```

When using from Java, Child have only default and Child(String name) constructors (and Map, for sure), but there are no Child(int id) and Child(int id, String name) constructors.

Is there any chance to get by  AST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also use the @InheritConstructors annotation on the `Child` class to bring in the expected constructors.

```
@Canonical @InheritConstructors
class Child extends Parent {
    String name
}
```

Comment: Ack... sadly, this approach does not work when using the `@Canonical` annotation since the constructors are generated after the fact. Not sure if I should delete this answer or let it stand as a related example.